# @SpringBootTest annotation on interfrace not working

Tags: spring, spring-test, junit5

It is not possible right now to place the annotation `SpringBootTest` on an interface, inherit from the interface and run the test.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
interface SpringBootTestBase

class GreetingControllerITest : SpringBootTestBase {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var restTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @Test
    fun `spring boot endpoint gets correct greeting`() {
        val body = restTemplate.getForObject("/greet/World", String::class.java)
        assertThat(body).isEqualTo("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

This fails with a NPE

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer.customizeContext(SpringBootTestContextCustomizer.java:50) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:326) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:625) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:365) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

The reason for this interface is, to put all annotations on the Interface and let all our tests inherit from that one -> avoid annotation-code-duplication

Using a base-class instead an interface is no real option for me, because I have other base-classes to inherit from, which are not test-related.

Would this be a useful feature I should bring to the spring community?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct: Spring Boot does not currently search for test related annotations on interfaces.

If you feel that would be useful, then please open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new) for Spring Boot.

On the other hand, if your primary goal is to avoid annotation duplication, then that is already supported since both core Spring and JUnit Jupiter support *composed annotations*.

For a concrete example of combining Spring, Spring Boot, and JUnit Jupiter annotations, take a look at the [`@SpringEventsWebTest`](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-events/blob/master/src/test/java/com/sambrannen/spring/events/web/SpringEventsWebTest.java) annotation in my [spring-events](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-events) sample project.

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework and core JUnit 5 committer)